# Fabric.js Resize object not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am unable to resize object I am using two inputs from where I get new width and height and the use that input value as new height and with for Active Object and object container is resizing but content is not.

```js
(function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';
    // create a rectangle with a fill and a different color stroke
    
    var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
     
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 50,
        top: 70,
        scaleX: .25,
        scaleY: .25
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
};
pugImg.src = imgURL;
    
    
    
    canvas.renderAll();   
    
    
    
$('#objSetterWidth, #objSetterHeight').bind('input', function() {  
   
  o = canvas.getActiveObject();
 w = $('#objSetterWidth').val();
 h = $('#objSetterHeight').val();
 o.width  =  w / o.scaleX
 o.height =  h / o.scaleY
  o.setCoords();
 canvas.renderAll();    
 
 
});
    
    
    
    
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Width" id="objSetterWidth">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Height" id="objSetterHeight">
  </div> 
    
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please don't put links to the code. Instead, type-in the relevant code snippets in your question.

Comment: Can you add the code on the message body please

Comment: yes i added the code

Answer (score 2):

This is what `width`/`height` do - they don't resize the original image but rather resize the container, effectively 'cropping' the original image. What you want to do is let fabric set the `width` and `height` according to the image's original dimensions and scale the object - this way you'll affect both image container and the image itself. You also don't need to pass `width` and `height` into `Image` constructor. If you want to add an image and scale to a particular size right away, use `scaleToWidth()` or `scaleToHeight()`.

Anyway, here's the code to resize the image via inputs:

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';
    // create a rectangle with a fill and a different color stroke
  var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {  
  var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
      //width: 500, //- you don't need this unless you want to 'crop'
      //height: 500, //- you don't need this unless you want to 'crop'
      left: 50,
      top: 70,
      scaleX: .25,
      scaleY: .25
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
    canvas.renderAll();
  };
  pugImg.src = imgURL;
    
  $('#objSetterWidth, #objSetterHeight').bind('input', function() {
    var o = canvas.getActiveObject();
    // if no object selected, do nothing
    if (!o) {
      return
    }
    var w = $('#objSetterWidth').val();
    var h = $('#objSetterHeight').val();
    // get the original image dimensions
    var originalW = o.getOriginalSize().width;
    var originalH = o.getOriginalSize().height;
    // if w input is empty, don't scale width
    if (w) {
      o.set('scaleX', w / originalW);
    }
    // if h input is empty, don't scale height
    if (h) {
      o.set('scaleY', h / originalH);
    }
    o.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Width" id="objSetterWidth">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Height" id="objSetterHeight">
  </div> 
    
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```